# Remover acentos do lado do banco de dados com Asp.net core Entity Framework

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-core

Possuo um metodo que recebo uma string, faz a busca e retorna todos os dados que forem iguais a palavra que eu passei, assim:

```
        public async Task<List<ProductDto>> GetAllAsync(string name)
        {
            IEnumerable<Product> lstProducts = new List<Product>();

            lstProducts = await _productRepository.GetAsync(c => c.Name.StartsWith(name));

            return ProductMapper.Mapper.Map<List<ProductDto>>(lstProducts);
        }
```

Tenho uma função que remove acentos `Utils.RemoveAccent(string palavra)` consigo remover perfeitamente do parametro name exemplificado acima, o problema é que no banco a palavra está com acento, por exemplo eu passei como pesquisa a palavra portugues e no banco tem um registro como portugês, como eu posso usar esse metodo que eu fiz, dentro da minha lambda acima?

ps: tentei algo como:

```
stProducts = await _productRepository.GetAsync(c => Utils.RemoveAccent(c.Name).StartsWith(name));
```

Porem nao deu certo.

Comment: criar um getter na proprieade `Name` no seu DTO que retorna o nome sem acento não resolveria?

Comment: eu tenho que remover o acento somente do retorno da pesquisa, porem o retorno para o usuario ainda tem que ir com acento, nao sei se conseguiu entender rsrs

Comment: ah entendi, e vc está usando LinqToEntities então o que vc tentou realmente não vai dar certo pq ele não sabe converter sua função para um SQL.
bem, como sugestão vc pode usar um SQL customizado (dá pra fazer com EF ou se preferir com o Dapper)

Comment: Cara depende do banco que você usa, no Sqlserver tem função para busca em texto, no Oracle você precisa criar um índice com função para fazer essa busca.
Se for o Sqlserver da uma olhada na consulta com freetext e contains, dependendo do que voce quer um dos dois te atente.
Mas assim, busca por texto em banco relacional é sempre um porre, as vezes compensa mais você usar um indexador tipo elastic ou um banco não relacional como RavenDb e mongo para isso